# custom servlet filter google endpoint

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I try to get my filter invoked but it seems it get ignored. So I have two quesstions:
1. How does the configuration looks like for a servlete filter with google endpoints?
2. Logging with slf4j (jdk logging as backend) should work properly in the filter class - I guess?

Configuration in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>myCoolFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.MyCoolFilterClass</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myCoolFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/endpoint-api-name/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServiceServlce</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.MyCoolEndpoint</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServiceServlce</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/endpoint-api-name/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found was to add the filter as a generic filter ( /*) and handle check the request URI:

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
log.info("request uri " + requestURI);
if (!requestURI.toLowerCase().contains("endpoint-api-name")) {
  chain.doFilter(req, resp);
  return;
}
```

It's worth noting that I also tried to use the servlet-name in the filter declaration - with no result. The only way I got the filter working was via /* url-pattern.